# How to select xml data from a sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm trying to write a sql query to get results as follows from a xml data type column in MS Sql Server 2012 database table
Data is stored in the database as follows

```
ID  |Summary
==========================
1   |<Summary><Field Key="Col1" Value="S1" /><Field Key="Col2" Value="N" /></Summary>
2   |<Summary><Field Key="Col1" Value="S2" /><Field Key="Col2" Value="Y" /></Summary>
```

I need a result set of records as follows

```
ID    |    Col1      |  Col2
==========================
1     |    S1        |  N
2     |    S2        |  Y
```

Can you please help me to sort this out?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read the help section - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .  Unfortunately, this is a very low quality question. You do not provide any meaningful details - database platform, etc.  Your question asks about XML, but you don't show any XML data.  Please read the help section, then update your question.

Comment: Extracting XML data is platform-specific.  Since we are not mind readers, it would be helpful if you told us.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using MSSQL's XML, you should get familiar with the XML type's `.query()` function.

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  1
                FROM    sys.objects
                WHERE   name = 'XMLParty'
                    AND type = 'U' )
BEGIN
    --DROP TABLE dbo.XMLParty;
    CREATE TABLE dbo.XMLParty
    (
        ID          INTEGER IDENTITY( 1, 1 ) NOT NULL,
                        PRIMARY KEY ( ID ),
        Summary     XML
    );
END;

INSERT INTO dbo.XMLParty ( Summary )
VALUES ( '<Summary><Field Key="Surname" Value="S1" /><Field Key="Action" Value="N" /></Summary>' );

INSERT INTO dbo.XMLParty ( Summary )
VALUES ( '<Summary><Field Key="Surname" Value="S2" /><Field Key="Action" Value="Y" /></Summary>' );
GO

SELECT  ID,
        Surname = Summary.value( '( ./Summary/Field/@Value )[ 1 ]', 'VARCHAR( MAX )' ),
        Value = Summary.value( '( ./Summary/Field/@Value )[ 2 ]', 'VARCHAR( MAX )' ),
        Summary.query( '.' )
FROM    dbo.XMLParty;
```

Using the results from `.query( '.' )` is absolutely, in every way, identical to simply selecting the `Summary` column, but the syntax is going to give you insight on how to use the `.value()` function for the results you want.  `.` is the root of your XML and from there, you can query node values ( `xmlField.value( '( ./Root/Node )[ n ]', 'VARCHAR( MAX )' )` or attributes ( as done above ) with `xmlField.value( '( ./Root/Node/@Attribute )[ n ]', 'VARCHAR( MAX )' )`.

There are a number of gotchas, like when using XML such as `<R><N><A v="1" /><A v="2" /></N><N><A v="3" /></N></R>`, `.value( '( ./R/N/A/@v )[ 3 ]', 'VARCHAR( MAX )' )` does not even remotely care that the A nodes are in different N nodes ( only cares about the level ), but again, `.query()` will help you figure a lot of that stuff out.

Answer (score 0):

You use the [value())](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) to extract value from XML. The first parameter is the XQuery expression used to locate the value and the second is the datatype.

The XQuery expression used below is `(/Summary/Field[@Key = "Col1"]/@Value)[1]`

If read from right to left is says:
Give me the first value found from the attribute `Value` where the attribute `Key` is `Col1` from the element `Field` where `Field` is child to `Summary` and `Summary` is the root element.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f7ac/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```sql
create table T
(
  ID int,
  Summary xml
)

insert into T values
(1, '<Summary><Field Key="Col1" Value="S1" /><Field Key="Col2" Value="N" /></Summary>'),
(2, '<Summary><Field Key="Col1" Value="S2" /><Field Key="Col2" Value="Y" /></Summary>')
```

**Query 1**:

```sql
select T.ID,
       T.Summary.value('(/Summary/Field[@Key = "Col1"]/@Value)[1]', 'varchar(10)') as Col1,
       T.Summary.value('(/Summary/Field[@Key = "Col2"]/@Value)[1]', 'varchar(10)') as Col2
from T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f7ac/1/0)**:

```
| ID | COL1 | COL2 |
|----|------|------|
|  1 |   S1 |    N |
|  2 |   S2 |    Y |
```